# Character Set utf8 giving syntax error

Tags: mysql

```
USE raimohuybrechts;
CREATE TABLE UnitBase
(
    Id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE CHARACTER SET utf8,
    Description VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    ShippingCostMultiplier FLOAT,
    Code VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Error is :

> line 4: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8, Description VARCHAR(1024)
>   CHARACTER SET utf8, Ship' at line 4

Can't really figure out what is wrong, as I use the exact same syntax on line 3, and it doesn't give an error there.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html Charset at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to set the character set at the table-level.

But if you need to set it at the column-level, the column-level `CHARACTER SET` specification is part of the `data_type`, so it needs to come before other modifiers such as `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE`, etc.

This should work:

```
CREATE TABLE UnitBase
(
    Id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Description VARCHAR(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    ShippingCostMultiplier FLOAT,
    Code VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't set Character to UTF8 to a field/column.

The correct string is:

```
CREATE TABLE UnitBase
(
    Id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR(1024),
    ShippingCostMultiplier FLOAT,
    Code VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8;
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you can, unless the docs are lying: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html)

Comment: Yes, you can set the character set at the column-level.